# Node: simulating network failure - res.status(404) not working

Tags: node.js, express

```
class gameInfo {
  static async gameeee(req, res) {
    try {
      console.log(req.body);
      await db.adb
        .collection("game")
        .findOne({ req.body.gameID}, async (err, result) => {
          console.log("a");
          if (err) {
            console.log("b");
            res.status(400);
          } else if (result === null) {
            console.log("c"); <------- this is called
            res.status(404);  <------ not happening
          } else if (result !== null) {
            res.json({ result });
          }
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400);
    }
  }
}
```

console result is

```
a
c
```

I am trying to simulate the response failure due to `no data`. However, `res.status(404)` is not working. How can I send the error?

Also, I am super confused with among `res.send`, `res.status` and `res.sendStatus`. What are the differences using these three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to `send` or `end` the response, see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status:

```
res.status(404).end();
```

And yes, as the documentation says, you could just use `sendStatus` instead.

> `res.sendStatus(404) // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found')`